# Oracle 12c - How to insert primary key of another table multiple times into a table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, oracle12c

I have `TABLE_A` with the columns:

```
table_id (PK) number;
table_1_id number;
table_2_id number;
```

and `TABLE_B`:

```
table_id number;
table_1_id number;
table_2_id number;
table_key number;
table_key_data varchar2(15);
```

I need to insert two records for each missing `TABLE_A.table_id` into `TABLE_B`.

This is how the data looks before:

```
table_1_id table_2_id table_id table_key table_key_data
1          123        12345    1         1111
1          123        12345    2         ABC
```

So if `TABLE_A` has the following `table_id`'s:

```
    12345
    23456
    34567    
..plus hundreds/thousands more
```

`TABLE_B` should look like this after the insert:

```
table_1_id table_2_id table_id table_key table_key_data
1          123        12345    1         1111
1          123        12345    2         ABC
1          123        23456    1         1111
1          123        23456    2         ABC
1          123        34567    1         1111
1          123        34567    2         ABC
...plus remaining hundreds/thousands more.
```

There may be more than 2 `table_key`'s for each `table_id`. So I need something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_B (SELECT 1,123,TABLE_A.TABLE_ID, 1 for the first record and 2 for second record etc, CASE WHEN table_key = 1 THEN '1111' WHEN table_key = 2 THEN '1111111' END FROM TABLE_A WHERE TABLE_A.TABLE_ID NOT IN (SELECT table_id FROM TABLE_B)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to explain how you get the data in table b.

Comment: @AbBennett Please see my post now.

Answer (score 0):

You can run 2 INSERT statements. Just add in your WHERE statement TABLE_A.TABLE_ID NOT IN (SELECT table_id FROM TABLE_B WHERE table_key = <1 or 2 depending on which insert you're doing>). This will allow you to do one at a time.